# Changing Button style's alternative like Bold button in Microsoft word in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, styles

my question is that 
is there any way for implementation a button like bold Button in word when click its background will be change , ""with out get boolean var"" ,
that means I want to know is there ant event or trigger or visualstate in xaml order to implement a button style when click its style will be change(during Working like word) and its style will come back to Normal style when click again ?
[image Bold Btn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABJoM.png)

Comment: use ToggleButton

Comment: You can achieve such appearance by specifying `Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}"` (can't find SO duplicate with such solution). And use `ToggleButton` of course.

Comment: thank you , @ASh .

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is with style triggers.  Like so...

```
    <ToggleButton Content="B" FontSize="20" Height="40" Width="40">
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
```